# prove that $\int ^1_0 u^2 dx \le \frac{1}{2}\int ^1_0 (u')^2 dx \; \forall u \in B $

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the following holds  $$u(x)=u(y)+\int ^x_y u'(t)dt$$

let $C'[0,1]$ be the set of fucntions $u:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ that are continious and have on $[0,1]$ consider the following subset of $C'[0,1]$
$B=\{u\in C'[0,1] :u(0)=0\}$

then prove that

$\int ^1_0 u^2 dx \le \frac{1}{2}\int ^1_0 (u')^2 dx \; \forall u \in B$$

how to start this question can some one help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus together with the hypothesis $u(0)=0$ we have:
$$
u(x)=\int_0^xu'(z)dz\leq \left(\int_0^x1dz\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^x(u'(z))^2dz\right)^{1/2}\leq x^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1(u'(z))^2dz\right)^{1/2}
$$
where we have used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $(u'(z))^2\geq 0$ for all $z\in[0,1]$. Then, 
$$
\int_0^1 u^2(x)dx\leq \int_0^1xdx\int_0^1(u'(z))^2dz=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1(u'(x))^2dx,
$$
which is the desired inequality.